# C# Dynamic LINQ Contains using an array only evaluates the first value

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable, dynamic-linq

Relatively new to C# and started using Dynamic LINQ to filter a data table adapter using a string. The issue I'm having is that the Where clause only seems to evaluate the first value in the string and none of the others. Here is the code I am using.

```
        string[] ids = new string[] { "12345", "67891", "45878" };
        var resultQ = (from pr in table1 select pr).AsQueryable();
        var iq = resultQ.Where("@0.Contains(FieldName)", ids);
```

It works but only for the first value "12345" so the output of iq displays all fields for "12345". I tried using linq.dynamic.core to see if that would help but the still same result (or I haven't used it properly). I know I'm probably missing something minor here but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also on a separate note: I wanted to convert the end result of iq which is a IQueryable type to EnumerationRowCollection type. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are `pr` and `table1` variables? Please, provide fully reproducible code.

Comment: Hi, table1 refers to the table adapter (table1 = TableAdapter1.GetData();) and pr is just a range variable used for rows. That isn't the issue it is to do with the dynamic LINQ contain statement not picking up all the values in the array. Cheers

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix both points now. Either set string[] to string for dynamic LINQ to get all values in list as coded below

```
string ids =  "12345,67891,45878";
var resultQ = (from pr in table1 select pr).AsQueryable();
var iq = resultQ.Where("@0.Contains(FieldName)", ids);
```

or use Syed's suggestion and change the LINQ query and keep the array (thanks again Seyed)

For the conversion of IQueryable type to EnumerationRowCollection I changed EnumerationRowCollection to IEnumerable and this worked for all my LINQ queries

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use this. It will works fine.

```
string[] ids = new string[] { "12345", "67891", "45878" };

var resultQ = (from pr in table1 select pr).AsQueryable();

var iq = resultQ.Where(w => ids.Contains(w.Id)).ToList();
```

Comment: Awesome thanks Syed, that works too! I also wanted to convert that iq list to EnumerableRowCollection type is this possible? cheers

Comment: Welcome. ToList will not fulfil your requirement? what you want then let me know

Comment: I wanted to use iq in another LINQ method to group by and sum. I have added the LINQ method into a function to be used in a number of different places with parameters but I get a "lamda expression with statement body cannot be converted to expression tree " when I use the following. Works without using IQueryable                                                                            
        .Select(g =>
                  {
                      DataRow row = table1.NewRow();
                      row[field] = g.Key;
                      row[aggr] = g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>(aggr));